# how to be able to keep using a page(clickin,tasks etc..) while a javascript is still being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

i have designed a dashboard that auto refresh every 30 seconds.

i am using jquery and so i we take the tab "new users" on the dasboard, it has a code like that:

```
<li>New users Today: <span id="NbOfNewUsers">
  <script>refreshStatContent('Users')</script></span>
</li>
```

now the script resfreshStatContent uses jquery $.ajax to get users content:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "usersctnt.php",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml)
   {
        }
       });
```

ok the problem is, even though ajax goes asynchronous, but still the fact that am using `<script>refreshStatContent(\'Users\')</script>` imposes that this javascript function finishes loading before i can do any task on the page. Right now if i try to click on a link on the page while the user content is loading, it doesn't let me... until the `refreshStatContent(\'Users\')` is finished...

is there a way to be able to still use the page even when a script is loading?

thanks a lot, much appreciated

Comment: There's not enough code to provide context. Is `refreshStatContent` doing something else that blocks JS, or do the inactive links you're clicking on depend on content that's loaded from userscntn.php, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using you script like this:

```
<li>New users Today: <span id="NbOfNewUsers">
  <script>refreshStatContent('Users')</script></span>
</li>
```

you should include all of your javascript at the bottom of the page.
Make a function that calls refreshStatContent on the span like this:

include jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       // do stuff when DOM is ready
       var usrList = efreshStatContent('Users');
       $(#NbOfNewUsers).append(usrList);       
     });
</script>
</body>
```

Or you might even want to extract all of you js to an external file, so it is need and clean.